# Check if a field value exists in another SharePoint list before creating an item

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I want to check if an item value exists in another list before saving it using PreSaveAction function. The value I want to check is EventDate

```js
function PreSaveAction()    {
var time = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue();
alert(time);
//Validation for current fields

  if(SPUtility.GetSPField('Field').GetValue() == "yes")
{
     alert('Validation passed, let SharePoint continue');
     return true;}
else
{
alert('Validation failed, let SharePoint not continue');
     return false;
}
}
```

And I get the items from the second list with this:

```js
function ViewItem()
{
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('demoTrainingRoom2');
var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
allItems = list.getItems(query);
context.load(allItems, 'Include(Title, EventDate)');

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
}

function success() {
 
//var contador = this.allitems.getCount(); 
var TextFiled = "";
var ListEnumerator = this.allItems.getEnumerator();
var firstListTime = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue();
while(ListEnumerator.moveNext())
{
var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();
TextFiled += currentItem.get_item('Title') + '-' + currentItem.get_item('EventDate'); +'\n';
}
alert(TextFiled);
}

function failed(sender, args) {
alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
}
```

So basically I want to check if any item on list 1 has the same EventDate on list 2 when using PreSaveAction. Any help will be kindly appreciated

**UPDATE**

Thank you for the interest, now i can succesfully check if a value on the first list exist in the second list with the following code. Now I need to pass the output of that check to the PreSaveAction function when demoField is equal to yes

```js
function ViewItem()
{
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('demoTrainingRoom2');
var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
allItems = list.getItems(query);
context.load(allItems, 'Include(Title, EventDate)');

context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success), Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
}

function success() {
 
var currentTitle = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue(); 
for(var i = 0; i < this.allItems.get_count(); i++){
      var item = this.allItems.get_item(i);
      console.log(item.get_item('EventDate'));
                           
                     if (currentTitle === item.get_item('EventDate')){
                     alert('I exist on the second list' + ' ' + item.get_item('EventDate'));
                      return true; // or item
          }
      }
      return false;
    }


function failed(sender, args) {
alert("failed. Message:" + args.get_message());
}


function PreSaveAction()    {

var time = SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue();


if(SPUtility.GetSPField('demoField').GetValue() == "yes")
{
   //Saving File
     
     return true;}
else
{ 
    //NOt saving FIle
     return false;
}
}
```

Thank you in advance for the assistance

Comment: What version of SharePoint is this for, and which method are you planning on using to add the JavaScript to the form?

Comment: I'm currently using sharepoint 2013 and I put a a script in the masterpage so if the url match the url from the lists call a js with the PreSavedAction

Comment: Firstly,  Putting script that will never execute into a master page will create overheard for all sites outside this list/URL,  you would be better putting it into a single page.
Secondly, where are you calling this "PreSaveAction" method?

Answer (score 0):

call the PreSaveAction() method inside the your first list OnSuccess() method , pass event date as a caml query to the second list i.e query 2nd list on event date ......... this is just snippet may contain some error , check out

```
 function ViewItem()
 {
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('demoTrainingRoom2');
var query = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();
allItems = list.getItems(query);
 context.load(allItems, 'Include(Title, EventDate)');

  context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.success),Function.createDelegate(this, this.failed));
}

  function success() {

 var TextFiled = "";
var ListEnumerator = this.allItems.getEnumerator();
 var firstListTime =        SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('EventDate').GetValue();
while(ListEnumerator.moveNext())
 {

 var evtDate = currentItem.get_item('EventDate');

function PreSaveAction() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List2');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'EventDate\'/>' + 
    '<Value Type=\'DateTime\'>'+ evtDate  +'</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,       this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

 }

 }
 function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

var listItemInfo = '';

var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {

    alert('event date exist')

  }    
 }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' +   args.get_stackTrace());
 }
```

Comment: Thyank you for the interest @vinayak hegde now i can succesfully check if a value on the first list exists on the second list, I updated my post if you want to check it out, now  I just need to pass the output of that check to the function PreSaveAction